# What is the run time complexity of this code?

Tags: python, time-complexity

I just got this in an interview question, but got stumped on mod, my answer was O(log10) because it was divided every-time, but I couldn't explain it. So i switched my answer to O(n) but the interviewer said what does n represent, and I was going to say x, but that didn't make sense. if x is 1000, the code doesn't run 1000 times.

`x` is any number 1-10000000

```
def code(x):
    count = 0
    while x > 0:
        x = x // 10
        result = x % 7
        if (result % 7 )== 0:
            count += 1
    return count
```

Comment: `I was going to say x, but that didn't make sense. if x is 1000, the code doesn't run 1000 times.` Correct, thats why its not `O(n)`.

Comment: Your first answer was correct, it's O(log x) since you divide by a constant amount every iteration.

Comment: For big-O purposes, the base of the logarithm is irrelevant, since that's just a constant multiplier, and we discard these coefficients.

Comment: The first answer was *not* correct, maybe only because of a typo. There is no variable in log 10, so we have to assume that 10 is not the base, but the argument to the log function. O( log(10) ) = O(1). I guess you *meant* O( log_10(x) ) which is the same as O( log(x) ).

Comment: If there's an upper bound on `x`, the algorithm is indeed O(1).

Comment: Is there a specific reason is `% 7` taken twice?

Comment: no specific reason, the code is what i remember from the first part of the interview, whatever i recollected. i did remember two of the %7s, probably to throw us off in a high-pressure situation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The while loop executes about *log<sub>10</sub>x* times. The rest is constant-time operations. Therefore, your time complexity is ***O(log x)***. Notice that in big-O notation, the base of the logarithm does not matter.

A more complicated question is what value will `count` have with respect to `x`. But this is not what you asked for. Notice that these calculations (assuming constant-time arithmetic operations) take constant time, just like the line `x = x // 10`.

**Edit:** If `x` is bounded above, it turns into a philosophical question whether the time complexity is *O(log n)* or *O(1)*. It depends on how you view it (is the bound a part of the algorithm, or do you view the algorithm as general and the bound just something you know about the input you will get to it).